# IEEEconf makes figures vanish through addtolength{\textheight}

Tags: graphics, ieeeconf

I have to write a small paper in ieeeconf style. Everything works fine, except that my figures vanish.

I have narrowed it down to the following: At the end of the document, there is a line saying

```
\addtolength{\textheight}{-12cm}   % This command serves to balance the column lengths
                                  % on the last page of the document manually. It shortens
                                  % the textheight of the last page by a suitable amount.
                                  % This command does not take effect until the next page
                                  % so it should come on the page before the last. Make
                                  % sure that you do not shorten the textheight too much.
```

If I comment out this line, everything works fine, but as soon as I leave it in, my figures disappear.

My guess is the following: The line limits the number of figures which can be present in one column. Additional figures are sent to the next page, which for some reason is cut off.

My minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt, conference]{ieeeconf}  % Comment this line out if you need a4paper

%% My packages:
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

%%     
\title{\LARGE \bf
Very long title with lots of spoilers allowing to skip the actual paper
}

\author{Albert Author$^{1}$ and Bernard D. Researcher$^{2}$% <-this % stops a space
\thanks{*This work was not supported by any organization}% <-this % stops a space
\thanks{$^{1}$Albert Author is with Faculty of Electrical Engineering, Mathematics and Computer Science,
        University of Twente, 7500 AE Enschede, The Netherlands
        {\tt\small albert.author@papercept.net}}%
\thanks{$^{2}$Bernard D. Researcheris with the Department of Electrical Engineering, Wright State University,
        Dayton, OH 45435, USA
        {\tt\small b.d.researcher@ieee.org}}%
}

%
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{figure}
\centering
    \begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
        \includegraphics*[width=\columnwidth]{logo}
        \caption{A}
        \label{fig:c1}
    \end{subfigure} \\
    \begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{logo}
        \caption{B}
        \label{fig:c2}
    \end{subfigure} \\
    \begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{logo}
        \caption{C}
        \label{fig:c3}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{My overall caption}
    \label{fig:main_label}
\end{figure}

%\addtolength{\textheight}{-12cm} % <-- IF I UNCOMMENT THIS LINE, THE FIGURES ABOVE DISAPPEAR

\end{document}
```

NOTE:
If I delete the .aux file and compile it once, the figures are present. At the second compilation however, they disappear again. Unfortunately, I need to compile twice since the labels etc. are only set then.

Comment: changing `\textheight` mid document simply isn't supported, it can be done with care (eg lscape package does this) but only at a forced page break with `\clearpage` to flush all pending floats..

Comment: Thanks, that resolves it! I will simply comment it out and submit it as such, see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing `\textheight` mid document simply isn't supported, it can be done with care (eg lscape package does this) but only at a forced page break with `\clearpage` to flush all pending floats..